# Why does't C allow member functions in structs?

Tags: c, struct

One of the big differences between C and C++ is member functions within the struct. C doesn't allow functions as members in structs. I know a workaround is to use function pointer as struct member, but that is only function simulation, it breaks the scope rules.

If C allowed real functions as members of structs, it would be a great feature. But I don't know why C doesn't do that. Is there any particular reason?

Comment: Why dual-sim card phone supports 2 sim cards and your old phone has only one sim card? Ask manufacturer why you cannot put 2 sim cards in the old model. Your questiion is similar...

Comment: Why your fan doesn't allow temperature and humidity control? You air-conditioner can warm the air up or cool it down, it can also moisturize and dry it – it would be a great feature it the fan could do that, too...

Comment: Public member functions in C are written as file scope functions which take a pointer to the struct type as parameter. Similarly, private member functions are also at file scope but declared `static`. It is just different syntax. Just don't tell C++ fans that you can write OO code in C or they always get very aggressive; means they learnt that whole bloated language for nothing :)

Comment: I will see how much negative votes I will have. That's really interesting that how people don't like my question, and their attitude is either based on  fact or emotion

Comment: to CiaPan: If you can build fan with humi and temp control without any further difficulty and keeping the same price, you will kill all air conditioner manufacturer

Comment: @i486, do you know why iphone 3,4,5,6,7... don't have dual sim?

Comment: Explain us what you will do with member functions? Maybe you will simulate object oriented programming? Without inheritance, only member functions are useless feature. Instead of member function, define global function with parameter of structure pointer type, then add the "object" (address of variable) and call the function. Will have the necessary behaviour.

Comment: a simple example, state machine. a state has both data and action, if c struct can have member function in it, one struct definition is enough to represent a state.
a function pointer can mimic action but that is not real member function and simply breaks scope rules as I mentioned below.

Comment: Mainly because Ritchie wanted the binary representation of a `struct` to be as straightforward as possible (it's the reason he gives for why array expressions "decay" to pointers; he couldn't figure out a good way to store the pointer that B's array semantics demanded).

Comment: The first C++ compilers did not directly compile code. They translated C++ into C and then compiled that C code.  Therefore anything code-able in early C++ was code-able, _somehow_, in C.

Answer (score 9):

You're looking at it backwards.

C wasn't designed by starting from C++ and then removing features. C was designed by starting from older languages, including B, FORTRAN and the assembler languages of that time.

Working their way up from there, the designers of C added features that represented patterns that often appeared in contemporary code, such as data types (instead of working with bits), user-defined composite types (structs), cleanly separated functions (instead of an instruction stream and jumping here and there), passing arguments (instead of passing them manually through the registers and the stack, retrieving them accordingly, then manually cleaning up), and so on.

Working their way up from there, now the designers of OOP languages added features that represented patterns that often appeared in contemporary code, such as functions that go hand-in-hand with the data they operate on (methods), data types with inheritance (instead of just composition), visibility control and encapsulation (instead of hiding things behind opaque pointers), polymorphism at the call spots (instead of explicitly checking internal flags that represent the data type), and so on.

It should be clear by now: How did the designers of C++ introduce so many features? Because C was already there, and they could begin from there. Why didn't the designers of C introduce all those features to begin with? Well, because *those* people were too busy designing C itself.

The point is, every successful language that came along was typically an improvement *over previous ones*. Everything that C offered made programming safer and easier, *compared to how it was before*. Sure, it didn't have every feature we have today, but even in retrospect, it wasn't supposed to - language designers needed to see *in practice* what kinds of things would be needed by programmers from there on.

Comment: C is essentially a glorified macro-assembler for the PDP-11.

Comment: Personally I think there must be some difficulties that is really hard or event impossible to implement in c compiler

Comment: @c-stranger A C compiler is comparatively easy to implement. For all the languages I know, only a Pascal compiler is easier to implement.

Comment: @c-stranger What makes you think there's something that would be impossible to implement/introduce in C?

Comment: If you google member function in c struct, you will see quite a lot people asking similar question, so I'm not alone. The member function in c struct will significantly extend c functionality, but why not to do that, perhaps only the author of c can answer this.

Comment: @c-stranger There's nothing particularly hard about implementing it, when you have a working C compiler. The committee probably doesn't believe that C needs this, that's all. People who want member functions probably want other missing features too, and those people would probably migrate to another language soon, anyway.

Comment: That possibly would be a reason that the designer 'think' it is not a necessary feature when they invented c language.

Answer (score 6):

Because C is not C++.  They are different languages.

Comment: That is not real cause.

Comment: *That is not real cause.*  OK, what's the *real cause* that makes you want features from one language implanted into another, somewhat like walking into a hardware store and asking why hammers don't have a wrench built into the end of the handle because you think it'd be useful?

Comment: please google hammer wrench, you will find hammer built with wrench

Comment: *please google hammer wrench, you will find hammer built with wrench*  Good Lord, you don't even know what a hammer wrench is.  Hint:  it's not a **hammer** with a wrench hanging off the end.  Please Google *tool*.  It seems apropos.

Comment: please let me know if the following is what you are looking for:
http://www.fhmine.com/products-page/tools-2/rastall-hammer-head-miners-wrench/
http://www.kfd.com.au/shop/item/hammer-wrench

Answer (score 0):

Mixing data with their function is usually done only in Object-orientated programming (OOP).

Since C was not designed to be OOP-like (it is a procedural language, most OOP language were developed later in history), it does not make sense to mix data with functions.

Comment: Bjarne got `class` and member functions from [the Simula language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula), which existed before C.

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks, corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

C is a procedure oriented language and C++ is a object oriented language.
Object oriented language simulates everything as the object of real world.
A class is the type of object and it can have properties and methods(functions).
If you want make struct to have function in it, it would be another type of programming language.
Please don't mix procedure oriented language with object oriented language.

Comment: Procedure oriented vs object oriented is not mutually exclusive. While C isn't OO language, using OO techniques with strict naming conventions can make certain C modules a lot cleaner. Imitating non-virtual methods in C is trivial: `int ClassName_MethodName(ClassName_T * object, int param1);` for example.